# What is wrong with this conditional statement?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I am trying to have the navigation highlights determined by what category or page you are looking at using wordpress. Can someone tell me what is wrong with a statement like this:

```
<?php if (in_category('b')){ ?>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
        <li><a class="current" href="#">B</li>
    </ul>
<?php } else { ?>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="current" href="#">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">B</li>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

I am trying to use something like this but my else statement is ignored and the 'b' is always current regardless of category.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Have you considered to use a template engine? This embedded html burns my eyes ;-)

Comment: Yes it does Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams. It is a valid code. Not sure about the function `in_category()`

Comment: @Starx: Just because the code is valid doesn't mean that it's ever run.

Comment: @Ignacio, My point is  `It executes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are either not inside a post or everything is in category 'b'.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category for in_category() information.

Comment: No everything is not in cat b and I am not sure what you mean by not inside a post.  This can be done outside the loop as it shows in that link.

Comment: `This tag can be used to test the current post within The Loop` If you are in The Loop, in_category() will test the current post against the category.  If you are outside The Loop, you should provide the post id as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

read [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

You've got to write something like:

```
<?php if (in_category('b')): ?>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
  <li><a class="current" href="#">B</li>
  </ul>

...
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried that too and it makes no difference.  I think that is just alternate syntax, reading preference..

Comment: I didn't think that your syntax even works... PHP is a strange language. In this case, it's a logic error somewhere.

Comment: The alternative syntax is not required for wordpress, it's just the way they like to write it.